# Select records that hasn't been query before Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, select

How can I retrieve only records that haven't been queried before?

For example:

If I have 3 record in my table:

- Record 1
- Record 2
- Record 3

And I make a query like

```
`SELECT * FROM TABLE`
```

I will get the three record above. If I inserted three more records and I make the query again I just want to see:

- Record 4
- Record 5
- Record 6

Is there a way to make this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like bad engineering / platform design. What's the use case for this?

Comment: add a bit there so you would know this record already selected

Answer (score 3):

A reliable approach is adding some sort of flag to the table that indicates whether the row has been "read" before, and query as follows:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE read_flag = 0 FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE my_table SET read_flag = 1 WHERE id = my_table.id;

COMMIT;
```

Note that this requires the InnoDB engine.

Comment: This answer requires the table engine InnoDB before it works.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @RaymondNijland excelent!! It works for me thank you!

Comment: EmilePels posted this answer not me @JonathanRojas.. i only posted a comment about the requirement off InnoDB.. just accept this anwer if it helpt you out .

Answer (score 0):

Which programming langauge are u using?

You could save the id of "Record3", and then query:

```
select * from table where id > (id_from_record_3)
```

Comment: Even `auto_increment` are not necessarily sequential and ordered.